# Java X25519 shared secret is not correct when using testing vectors from RFC7748

Tags: java, elliptic-curve, rfc, diffie-hellman, x25519

When using [RFC7748 test vectors](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-6.1) for elliptic curve diffie hellman in java, I cannot get expected shared secret key. I am able to do so in other languages. I am using openjdk 11 with default Sun security provider. I found [official tests](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/test/jdk/sun/security/ec/xec/TestXDH.java) which use these test vectors. But I cannot get expected result even if I copy-paste and run them. For instance, [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/test/jdk/sun/security/ec/xec/TestXDH.java#L264) is test that uses these same vectors which will fail if I copy-paste and run locally. It uses some utility functions which are from [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erriggs/webrev-hex-security-8252055/test/lib/jdk/test/lib/Convert.java-.html), which I also copied. I know I must be doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what exactly. Here is my code:

```
public class main {
    public static BigInteger hexStringToBigInteger(boolean clearHighBit, String str) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
            int curVal = Character.digit(str.charAt(2 * i), 16);
            curVal <<= 4;
            curVal += Character.digit(str.charAt(2 * i + 1), 16);
            if (clearHighBit && i == str.length() / 2 - 1) {
                curVal &= 0x7F;
                result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(curVal).shiftLeft(8 * i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String str) {
        byte[] result = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) Character.digit(str.charAt(2 * i), 16);
            result[i] <<= 4;
            result[i] += Character.digit(str.charAt(2 * i + 1), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] arr) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte curVal : arr) {
            result.append(Character.forDigit(curVal >> 4 & 0xF, 16));
            result.append(Character.forDigit(curVal & 0xF, 16));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static void runDiffieHellmanTest(String curveName, String a_pri,
                                             String b_pub, String result) throws Exception {

        NamedParameterSpec paramSpec = new NamedParameterSpec(curveName);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("XDH");
        KeySpec privateSpec = new XECPrivateKeySpec(paramSpec, hexStringToByteArray(a_pri));
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
        boolean clearHighBit = curveName.equals("X25519");
        KeySpec publicSpec = new XECPublicKeySpec(paramSpec, hexStringToBigInteger(clearHighBit, b_pub));
        PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(publicSpec);

        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = privateKey.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("Encoded private: " + byteArrayToHexString(encodedPrivateKey));
        byte[] encodedPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("Encoded public: " + byteArrayToHexString(encodedPublicKey));

        KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("XDH");
        ka.init(privateKey);
        ka.doPhase(publicKey, true);

        byte[] sharedSecret = ka.generateSecret();
        byte[] expectedResult = hexStringToByteArray(result);
        if (!Arrays.equals(sharedSecret, expectedResult)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail: expected=" + result + ", actual="
                    + byteArrayToHexString(sharedSecret));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runDiffieHellmanTest(
                "X25519",
                "77076d0a7318a57d3c16c17251b26645df4c2f87ebc0992ab177fba51db92c2a",
                "de9edb7d7b7dc1b4d35b61c2ece435373f8343c85b78674dadfc7e146f882b4f",
                "4a5d9d5ba4ce2de1728e3bf480350f25e07e21c947d19e3376f09b3c1e161742");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a potentially good question, but you haven't followed the guidelines for posting here. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and especially read [ask].  You are expected to include your code in the question, not as a link which will eventually go 404.  Questions must be self-contained so they remain a resource for future visitors.  Please [edit] your question and include all appropriate code, data and error messages/complete stack trace (if applicable).  Format stack traces and error messages the same as code.

Comment: Your method `hexStringToBigInteger` looks wrong. I'm not really sure what you're doing there with "clearing the high bit", but BigInteger already has a constructor [`BigInteger(String value, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)) to do this. Just do `new BigInteger("de9edb7d7b7dc1b4d35b61c2ece435373f8343c85b78674dadfc7e146f882b4f", 16)` for example.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: what I take to be [the real version](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/test/lib/jdk/test/lib/Convert.java#L64) has comments explaining the little-endianness of XDH public values (it's a Bernstein quirk) and it is specified in section 5 of rfc7748 along with the need in general (though not for these testcases) to clear the high bit of the high-order=rightmost byte. The Java ctor you reference is for big-endian.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: ok, then the problem is simply that `hexStringToBigInteger` throws away every byte by resetting `curVal` at the top of the loop. Only for the last iteration through the loop does the value get retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly swapped two lines in `hexStringToBigInteger`:

```
            if (clearHighBit && i == str.length() / 2 - 1) {
                curVal &= 0x7F;
                result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(curVal).shiftLeft(8 * i));
            }
```

should instead be:

```
            if (clearHighBit && i == str.length() / 2 - 1) {
                curVal &= 0x7F;
            }
            result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(curVal).shiftLeft(8 * i));
```

Comment: So Java implementation does not clear MSB of high order byte. And since `XECPublicKeySpec` already expects `BigInteger` instead of byte array, it already has to be in little-endian format. I could also do `hexStringToByteArray` to get bytes, then `&= 0x7F` last byte and reverse whole array before feeding it into `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not establish shared secret between Go and Java applications, so I tried to debug what was the cause of that which led me into reading `RFC7748` and digging through source code for `X25519` key exchange in Java. So for people who want to perform `X25519` key exchange between Java and some other non-Java application - here is main takeaway. Java already expects input public key to be `BigInteger` instead of byte array. Some other languages may return public key as a byte array in `big-endian` format. Due to `RFC7748` specification, `X` coordinate of a point on elliptic curve (which is your public key byte array) **must be in `little-endian` format**. So you only have to reverse input public key byte array to make it `little-endian`, before feeding in to `BigInteger`.